# Can Received Pronunciation pronounce written "r" /l/? Why?

Tags: british-english

Why does Major Fraser (acted by [Lance Lockhart-Ross](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm5439756/)) pronounce [perimeter](https://youtu.be/yCDJSVmxHkg?t=4739) ([/pəˈrɪm.ɪ.tə<sup>r</sup>/](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-chinese-traditional/perimeter) or [/pəˈrɪmɪtə(r)/](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/perimeter) ), like "pe**L**imeter" (/pəˈ**l**ɪm.ɪ.tə<sup>r</sup>/) ?  Fraser's accent sounds Received Pronunciation of British English, correct?

> I overheard. We can cover the perimeter. But surely we can dig in.

##### In general, when does Received Pronunciation pronounce  written "r"  as /l/?

In case this video gets removed, I linked to 1:18:59 / 1:34:46 of the 1968 movie *Majuba: Heuwel van Duiwe*. Right after Major General Colley spoke to Colonel Stewart, this scene shows Major Fraser speaking to Colonel Stewart on their ascendance  to [Majuba Hill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Majuba_Hill).

I never studied IPA. Please correct this post if I mistook symbols. I perused [Why does the British accent make "R" sound like "l"?](https://www.quora.com/Why-does-the-British-accent-make-R-sound-like-l) to no avail.

Comment: Lance Lockhart-Ross is speaking in what he believes to be a 'clipped' British upper-class accent (which is not the same as 'RP'). The actor is in fact South African, not British, which explains the odd pronunciation.

Comment: It doesn't sound like 'l' to me, just a very minimal 'r' sound.

Comment: I agree.  It does not sound like *L* to this US English speaker either, although the actor does minimize the *R* so much that it's almost *pe'imiter*.

Comment: Some with RP accwents, and other accents do have issues with r sounds, but I can't really detect an issue here.  Quite the contrary, the "r" sounds rather trilled to me - which is a fearure of older varieties of RP, the more clipped version common in old films, sometimes called ultra RP.  It sounds distincly old fashioned now.

Comment: @BillyKerr - yes, and also common in some older London 'Cockney' type accents. It should be noted that this is a South African film, and it would appear that most if not all of the cast was also South African. That country's 'white' population, then and now, was divided into 'English' and 'Afrikaans' speakers. The 'English' ones, descendants of British colonists, spoke (and speak) with a distinct accent similar in many ways to UK 'RP', but not at all identical. This actor was trying for an 'English' accent of a particular time and class, and whether he was successful is a matter of opinion.

Comment: Yup - for example: Jonafan Woss. LOL. Although I'm not sure I really detect a South African accent here. Might be though. In old films, the RP they used back then did generally have a stronger R sound than today, especially when the R was between two vowels.

Comment: @BillyKerr - The accent of English speaking South Africans (and 'Rhodesians') has often had a very exaggerated (to native UK ears) 'upper-class' intonation, and can sound as if it's shifted back in time a decade or two. it's also much more clipped. I don't mean a 'Boer' type accent. Try listening to Doris Lessing (Rhodesia from age 6 to 30) although I can hear a sort of colonial twang there, a bit like New Zealanders.

Comment: @MichaleHarvey - yeah , it's a fascinating subject, how accents change over time. My only fear is that 20 years from now the whole of Britain will be speaking Mockney. It seems to be going that way. And by the time the UK finally adopts a spelling reform, they will change the spelling of "think" to "fink" ;)

Comment: Not if I have anything to do with it (accent and spelling). If I am alive 20 years from now, I'll probably sound even more like Oliver on The Archers than I do now. Have you noticed Prince Harry trying to speak Estuary? Makes me cringe.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey **1.** How do you know that Lance Lockhart-Ross "is in fact South African, not British"? His [double-barreled surname](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-barrelled_name#British_tradition) sounds English. I know *Majuba* is a South African movie, but they hired some English actors like [Kenneth Baker](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0048650/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t29) who played Captain Lang. **2.** "'clipped' British upper-class accent (which is not the same as 'RP')" Please elaborate why  a British upper-class accent differs from RP? **3.** What do you mean by "clipped"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In RP the /r/ is not produced as [l]. It is generally either a labialized postalveolar approximant  [ɹ̠ʷ] or sometimes an  alveolar flap [ɾ].

It is not produced as a alveolar lateral approximant [l] or its "dark" or velarised form [ɫ].

The consonant might be reduced in some accents, and individuals may have idiosyncratic pronunciation, or speech defects. Your example doesn't sound like [l] to me, but a rather short, "clipped" r-sound.